# remove second admin menu

Tags: 7, navigation

This is a pretty basic problem I think but i can't seem to find the solution. I've install the adminimal menu and I would like to remove the second menu on the bottom of this image. I've disable toolbar.

[image]

Comment: What links do you see when you click on the hamburger menu and what happens whten you click on + button?

Comment: Which theme are you using, I think this is not coming from Adminimal_admin_menu, It is coming from your theme.

Comment: @longboardnode, clicking on the hamburger menu give me a page with links to : dashboard, content, structure, appearance, people, module, configuration, reports, help. and the + is adding nodes type.

Comment: @CodeNext, I am using Sizzle 7.x-1.1 (default theme) A starter theme for Open Restaurant based on Radix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[navbar](https://www.drupal.org/project/navbar) was enable. I disable it and the hambuger menu was gone.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Disable Toolbar module from core section in module list,
hope it helps

Comment: I've disabled Toolbar already.